# Xpath parsing issue

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to find the right xPath string to parse this XML example. At the moment I can't get it because of the 'self closing' elements.

This is a section of the XML i'm processing.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <getRecordsResponse xmlns="http://www.dummy.com">
         <getRecordsResult>
            <business_duration/>
            <calculation_complete>1</calculation_complete>
            <definition>0050aedb58064100ad1a7198c9974545</definition>
            <duration/>
            <end/>
            <field/>
            <field_value>PRODUKTIE</field_value>
            <id>b5f520716fae82001c41df971e3ee4e3</id>
            <start/>
            <sys_created_by>system</sys_created_by>
            <sys_created_on>2015-09-17 13:21:36</sys_created_on>
            <sys_id>0006a479c8a68200a7ffccf9faada3ce</sys_id>
            <sys_mod_count>0</sys_mod_count>
            <sys_updated_by>system</sys_updated_by>
            <sys_updated_on>2015-09-17 13:21:36</sys_updated_on>
            <table>cmdb_ci_db_ora_instance</table>
            <u_created_on_last_7_days>0</u_created_on_last_7_days>
            <u_old_value/>
            <u_uummss>152136</u_uummss>
            <u_yyyymmdd>20150917</u_yyyymmdd>
            <value>PRODUKTIE</value>
         </getRecordsResult>
      </getRecordsResponse>      
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

the problem is with "`<u_old_value/>`" for example with no string in it.

I would like to receive out of the XML all element names with or without values. So I can perform a next task with it.

like this:

```
                business_duration = NULL
                calculation_complete = 1
                definition = 0050aedb58064100ad1a7198c9974545
                duration = NULL
                end = NULL
                field = NULL
                field_value = PRODUKTIE
                id = b5f520716fae82001c41df971e3ee4e3
                start = NULL
                sys_created_by = system
                sys_created_on = 2015-09-17 13:21:36
                sys_id = 0006a479c8a68200a7ffccf9faada3ce
                sys_mod_count = 0
                sys_updated_by = system
                sys_updated_on = 2015-09-17 13:21:36
                table = cmdb_ci_db_ora_instance
                u_created_on_last_7_days = 0
                u_old_value = NULL
                u_uummss = 152136
                u_yyyymmdd = 20150917
                value = PRODUKTIE
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show the XPath you are currently using, and then we might see where you are having difficulty. The obvious way to get the string content of an element is using string(.) and that will work for empty elements just as well as for those with content - though it will give you a zero-length string, not the string "NULL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution!

the xPath the I needed was '`/*/*/*/*`'

Answer (score 0):

Here you are (XPath 2.0)

```
//getRecordsResult/*/concat(local-name(), '=', if(empty(text())) then 'Null' else string(text()))
```

in case of skipping the namespace

```
 //*[local-name()='getRecordsResult']/*/concat(local-name(), '=', if(empty(text())) then 'Null' else string(text()))
```

the result will be

```
business_duration=Null
calculation_complete=1
definition=0050aedb58064100ad1a7198c9974545
duration=Null
end=Null
field=Null
field_value=PRODUKTIE
id=b5f520716fae82001c41df971e3ee4e3
start=Null
sys_created_by=system
sys_created_on=2015-09-17 13:21:36
sys_id=0006a479c8a68200a7ffccf9faada3ce
sys_mod_count=0
sys_updated_by=system
sys_updated_on=2015-09-17 13:21:36
table=cmdb_ci_db_ora_instance
u_created_on_last_7_days=0
u_old_value=Null
u_uummss=152136
u_yyyymmdd=20150917
value=PRODUKTIE
```